# Swift UITableView On Reload Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some code I want to run on the function `onReload` of my UITableView. Basically for now I just want to print how many items there are in an array. Later on I will want to display or not display a view depending on how many items there is.

So I want this code to run whenever the UITableView refreshes or reloads or anything like that.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //dataArray is your data array
    // > 10 is your condition
    if dataArray.count >10{
        return 0
    }else{
        return dataArray.count
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't realize this function gets called every time. Thanks so much

Comment: Maybe you should figure principle of  `UITableViewDataSource/Delegate` out, you will save your time a lot